# remove zeros from nparray efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In the moment I am using this method:

```
data = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2,3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0]])
index = 0
idx = []
for img in range(len(data)):
    img_raw = np.any(data[img])
    if img_raw == 0.0:
        idx.append(index)
    index+=1
data = np.delete(data, idx, axis=0)
```

Does somebody know a better method?

Comment: Since your whole array contains solely zeros, you can just do `data = np.array([])`.

Comment: What's the desired result?  A copy-n-paste of your code doesn't change `data`.  `idx` is empty.  It almost looks like you want to delete rows that are entirely zeros.  `np.delete(data, [0,1,2,3,9,11,12], axis=1)` would remove selected columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whatever `data` is, Daniel answers for 1d-arrays, which appears to be sufficient in your case. If your `data` array is 2d, things become little bit more complicated since you cannot remove your 0s without altering the dimensions of your array. In this case, you may use [mask-arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.html)
 to remove non-wanted values from your considerations, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
ma_data = np.ma.masked_equal(data,0)
print(ma_data)
```

Any calculation, say mean, std, and so on, don't consider masked values.

Comment: Note that despite altering dimensions, @Daniel's answer does succeed in removing zeros in 2d and higher cases

Answer (score 7):

Use logical indexing:

```
data = np.zeros(500)
data = data[data!=0]
```

Comment: takes 4 sekonds